# Show reverse ManyToMany entries in Django Admin page

Tags: django, django-admin

In the classical example of [Articles/Publications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), when I create a Publication record in Admin page, I would like to be able to add existing Articles to that Publication. How can I do that?

I tried following:

```
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      articles = Article.objects.all()
admin.site.register(Publication, PublicationAdmin)
```

though I do not see any articles to select at all.

I can do the other way around, when I add a new article, I can select a publication by adding

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets =[('Publications', {'fields': ['publications']})]
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an `InlineModelAdmin` on the `through` model, in your case the `through` model is `Publication.article_set.through`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).